# How to prevent duplicate entries being added to DB table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this PHP/MySQL script which adds a comment into my DB:

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO blog_comments (article_id, author_name, comment, path, posted, status) ";
$SQL .= "VALUES (:article_id, :name, :comment, :next_path, Now(), 'Live');";

$STH = $DBH->prepare($SQL);
$STH->bindParam(':article_id', $article_id);
$STH->bindParam(':name', $name);
$STH->bindParam(':comment', $comment);
$STH->bindParam(':next_path', $next_path);
$STH->execute();
```

Is there any way to modify this so that it doesn't insert the same `[author_name]`, `[article_id]` and `[comment]` into this table? I know it's possible for one column by *adding UNIQUE* to my table, but not sure about multiple columns.

Comment: Certainly on article_id. Not sure about author_name though - dangerous for those who share the same name: John (Smith|Doe)

Comment: @nickhar: That's a very good point, thanks. This is simply to stop somebody refreshing the page and posting a duplicate entry. Perhaps I will use SESSION_ID as a unique user value...

Comment: Here's a better solution: After the user posts, redirect their browser. That way they can't refresh their post. Problem solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can add a `UNIQUE` constraint for multiple columns

```
CREATE TABLE
(
.....
CONSTRAINT tab_uq UNIQUE (author_name, comment)
)
```

or by altering the existing table,

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD UNIQUE (author_name, comment);
```

Comment: Huh, I never knew I could do that!! Thanks.

Comment: Your probably going to want to use [UPDATE] (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) or IGNORE as well to catch any possible dups and deal with them.

Answer (score 1):

call those columns as composite primary key..
that way, they will have a unique entry.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a unique key of multiple fields

Comment: not sure exactly the db you're using, but usually just field1+field2+field3 creates a composite key

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could check the db for a result before inserting data

Answer (score 1):

you can also check `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)